# Populate radiobuttons from datatable

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, radio-button

I'm making a questback in Windows forms (VB). I've succesfully setup the MySQL-database, and made connection with everything needed. I've also manage to populate a DataTable called tblAlt for the alternatives for the question.

Then I try to populate each radiobutton with rows from the DataTable.

Here's what I tried:

```
For Each row In tblAlt.Rows
    If tblAlt.Rows.IndexOf(row) = 0 Then
        RadioButton1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindAlt, "altTekst")
    ElseIf tblAlt.Rows.IndexOf(row) = 1 Then
        RadioButton2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindAlt, "altTekst")
    ElseIf tblAlt.Rows.IndexOf(row) = 3 Then
        RadioButton3.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindAlt, "altTekst")
    End If
Next
```

Unfortunately all 3 radiobuttons have the same text (the first row of the table).

Comment: Where are you setting the bindAlt variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't generally data bind individual rows of a table to controls on a form.  In your example code, you are databinding the same thing every time.

I suspect, this is all you want:

```
For Each row As DataRow In tblAlt.Rows
  If tblAlt.Rows.IndexOf(row) = 0 Then
    RadioButton1.Text = row("altTekst").ToString
  End If
  If tblAlt.Rows.IndexOf(row) = 1 Then
    RadioButton2.Text = row("altTekst").ToString
  End If
  If tblAlt.Rows.IndexOf(row) = 2 Then
    RadioButton3.Text = row("altTekst").ToString
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Studentactive.lblcourse.Text = dgvstclass2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Course Name").Value
        Studentactive.lblTeacher.Text = dgvstclass2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Teacher Name").Value
        Studentactive.lbltiming.Text = dgvstclass2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Timing").Value
        Studentactive.lblhide.Text = dgvstclass2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Rec#").Value

Comment: Could you please explain exactly what this code *does*? Posting a block of code by itself with no context isn't helpful.